# Unit testing multiple asynchronous calls that return promises with Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to understand how to best unit test my asynchronous CommonJS modules. I'm struggling to understand best practice when dealing with multiple chained promises.

Lets assume I have the following module defined:

```
module.exports = function(api, logger) {
    return api.get('/foo')
        .then(res => {
            return api.post('/bar/' + res.id)
        })
        .then(res => {
            logger.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            logger.error(err)
        })
}
```

and I have the following spec file trying to test that the correct calls are made.

```
var module = require('./module')
describe('module()', function() {
    var api;
    var logger;
    var getStub;
    var postStub;
    beforeEach(function() {
        getStub = sinon.stub();
        postStub = sinon.stub();
        api = {
            get: getStub.resolves({id: '123'),
            post: postStub.resolves()
        }
        logger = {
            log: sinon.spy(),
            error: sinon.spy()
        }
    })
    afterEach(function() {
        getStub.restore();
        postStub.restore();
    });
    it('should call get and post', function(done) {
        module(api, logger) // System under test
        expect(getStub).to.have.been.calledWith('/foo')
        expect(postStub).to.have.been.calledWith('/bar/123')
        done()
    })
})
```

This doesn't work. The first assertion passes correctly, but the second assertion fails, as presumably the promise hasn't resolved at the time of execution.

I can fix this using process.nextTick or setTimeout but I'd like to see how other people have solved this more gracefully.

I've tried adding chai-as-promised into the mix with little luck. My current setup includes, sinon, chai, sinon-as-promised and sinon-chai.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the fact that `module()` returns a promise, so you can add another `.then()` to the chain where you can assert the arguments (because at that point the previous `.then()` steps have been called, including the call to `api.post()`).

And since Mocha supports promises, you can return the resulting promise instead of having to deal with `done`:

```
it('should call get and post', function() {
  return module(api, logger).then(() => {
    expect(getStub).to.have.been.calledWith('/foo')
    expect(postStub).to.have.been.calledWith('/bar/123')
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems incredibly simple now. I was missing the return which was causing all sorts of issues dealing with done()